# Refreshing Power Pivot automatically

Tags: sql, excel, refresh, powerpivot

I hope that you can help me.
That's my situation: daily I'm importing in Power Pivot some data through a query on a SQL database.
Actually every morning I open the Power Pivot and I refresh it for import the data of the previous day present in the database.

This action require 20 minutes because I have a lot of data to import.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this action during the night, maybe an automatic refresh, so that I can open the file in the morning and I alredy have the data of the previous day.

I hope that I was clear with my request, thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Excel workbook is on a machine that does not shut down, you can keep the workbook open and configure the query to automatically refresh ever x minutes.

Or you can keep the workbook open and run VBA code to refresh the query on a timer.
There are plenty of examples for VBA timers if you just care to search.

Or you can configure the queries to refresh automatically when the file is opened, then create a Windows Task Scheduler job to open the workbook at a specific time. Again, the computer running this must be turned on.

You see that there are many options and they are all well documented and just a short google search away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; the Excel file is currently on a network drive that is always running and connected on internet. 
When I am in the office in the morning, I turn on the computer and connect to the network disk, open the file and update it manually. On the internet I found several solutions but they are not for me, because the excel file on the disk is closed, and because my computer is turned off at night.

Comment: Well, you cannot process a file without a running computer. Consider NOT turning off your computer at night, then you can implement any of the approaches above.

Comment: Ok, I can consider to let my computer turned on when I left the office. So now I have to set these thing: open the excel file on the network drive,( at 19:00 for example), and apply a method for doing these things: click on Data in the Excel top bar -> update all ->  save the file and close it -> turn off my computer. Can you help me for doing this ? Really apprecciate it.

Comment: Solve it, I've created a powershell script that do what I need when I leave the office. Thank for your support.